# Airline refuses to issue a refund, keeps stalling

Tags: airlines, refunds

I booked tickets with Viva Air from Medellin to Miami (I was in Colombia at the time). The flight was in August and I booked it May 4th. I found different (better) flight so I cancelled it within 24 hours and requested a refund online.

I still haven't got my money and any conversation with customer service ends the same: they keep saying it's being processed and there's nothing else they can do.

It's been almost 8 months, what can I do? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Didn’t you use a credit card?

Comment: Was the fare actually (fully) refundable? Do you have a confirmation of the cancellation and the amount you are owed?

Comment: @jcaron Many airlines offer free cancellation within 24 hours of online booking, regardless of fare rules, although this is less common than it used to be.

Comment: @jcaron US law requires free cancellation within 24 hours for US flights

Comment: Small claims. Also don't forget to add interest - 8 months is a long enough period in which it becomes relevant.

Comment: @JonathanReez I didn’t know that applied to foreign carriers as well. There must be quite a few airlines violating that rule...

Comment: That's kind of the definition of a jurisdiction, @jcaron. Want to play in their sandpit, play by their rules.

Comment: @Nij that’s not that easy, as other countries may see some measures as protectionism or infringing on their own rights or established treaties. See for instance EU261: it only applies for flights (from non-EU carriers) **departing** the EU, not the other way around. Good that in this case it applies to all, though.

Comment: @jcaron Yeah, foreign carriers and domestic carriers do operate under different sets regulations in the U.S. (and pretty much every other country, too,) but this particular regulation applies to all of them.

Comment: Again, that's what jurisdiction means, they get to make their rules for their sandpit and you don't have to like it. Other countries can complain all they want - but "protectionism" is what every country does to some degree, and whether it infringes other rights or obligations is something they'll have to push either diplomatically or through international tribunal. @jcaron

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you used a card, dispute it with your card provider, attaching the order and cancellation confirmations as evidence.

Comment: I've a feeling that disputes need to be raised within six months. Even if that's officially the case, it's still worth talking to your bank -- they might extend the deadline because of the airline's slowness.

Comment: Thank you, I waited that long because I did reach out to my bank and they opened a dispute with Mastercard who made the airline react within certain amount of time. Just got my money back today! Thanks, I would never have thought that a bank could help in this case but they did

Answer (score 19):

If disputing the charge with your card issuer doesn't work (or maybe even if it does,) you might want to consider [filing a consumer complaint against the airline with the U.S. Department of Transportation](https://www.transportation.gov/airconsumer/file-consumer-complaint).

All carriers operating flights to, from, or within the United States are required to have a customer service plan that meets at least the minimum standard of [14 CFR 259.5(b)(4)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/259.5), which says:

> Allowing reservations to be held at the quoted fare without payment, or cancelled without penalty, for at least twenty-four hours after the reservation is made if the reservation is made one week or more prior to a flight's departure;

The Department of Transportation also provides [guidance for how airline's may comply with this requirement](https://www.transportation.gov/sites/dot.gov/files/docs/Notice_24hour_hold_final20130530_0.pdf). It's also worth noting that the air carrier must have their policy for complying with this requirement on their website if they sell tickets on their website. Failure to provide such notification is also a violation of this regulation.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the above, I'd suggest taking the complaint *above* Customer Service level. Try to engage the airline's owners and directors. Their time is far more valuable than your refund and a persistent attempt to turn your issue into a conversation is likely to result in someone saying "let's just sort this" so they can get back to the business of running an airline.

Some useful contacts;

> VIVA Air CEO William Shaw - https://twitter.com/wnashaw?lang=en
>
> Irelandia Aviation CEO Declan Shaw - https://twitter.com/decfryan/status/1010272106062471168

You might also want to engage them via their twitter account. Complain vocally and link people to it. You'll typically find that you get a more rapid response because companies are afraid of poor publicity.

> https://twitter.com/VivaAirCol